# ASP.NET Redirection between pages belonging to different projects within same solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, redirect, visual-studio-2012

is it possible to redirect from page "first.aspx" belonging to "ProjectA" to page "second.aspx" belonging to "ProjectB" of the same solution?

I know when hosted the two projects will be different websites so we can easily call one page from another using normal http post/get. However is this possible while debugging in local visual studio environment?

**Regards**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting up multiple projects as the startup in visual studio, in my case "ProjectA" & "ProjectB", the two projects will have different URL:port and we can redirect from one to another. Make sure to take care of CORS.